# Facebook Javascript SDK thinks I'm a different user

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I created a second FB account for the purpose of testing logins, friend relationship functionality, etc.  Unfortunately, Facebook is telling me that the other account has not been authorized (even though I did - I'm just going to give it a day or so), however, that's not really the issue.

When trying to log into my app with my original FB profile, which definitely does have access rights, it appears that the app thinks I'm the other user and I'm getting the following message:

```
"App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions."
```

I'm getting this despite the fact that I've logged back into my primary FB account on facebook.com.  Is there a way for me to break all previous associations or refresh the user?  It might even be preferable to prompt the app user to put in his or her FB email and password at each login.  Is there a way to do that?

Also, when I log in from my phone, I don't get the error message.  It's as if the fact that I logged into the secondary account from my computer is blocking the normal login routine.

This is the Javascript that executes when I click the Facebook login button.

```
function checkLoginState() {
  FB.login(function(response) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    }, true);
  })
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So, you're a registered test user, or you've asked an app admin for permissions?

Comment: I take it you've cleared cache and cookies and any storageData from your browser?

Comment: I had cleared the cookies, but not the cache.  Clearing the cache did solve the problem, however, I don't want users to have to do that if two users want to login from the same device.  Is there a workaround that I can add to the logout() function?

Comment: Also, for whatever reason, it's not returning the email for the secondary facebook account (it is working for my primary FB account).  Maybe this has something to do with the verification issue I was referring to.  Here's the JS:

FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email, name'}, function(response) {......}  Any idea?

Comment: Have you requested `email` permission from the user, and did they grant it to your app? (Check /me/permissions, or debug the access token.)